# How to fetch file path from a folder through PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

We upload files on our library on weekly basis. I wanted to fetch the latest uploaded file path/URL from a folder through PL/SQL, but not sure if it's possible.

If possible, please suggest what should I do.

Comment: windows/linux, what version of Oracle?

Comment: It's Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Kyte wrote about accessing os-file-information utilizing the preprocessor directive a while ago. Perhaps this is what you are after.

[query the operating system](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-nov/o62asktom-1867739.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to use those APIs to do OS related work. it is important to note the GAP between OS and DB, DB should focus on data while other OS related work should be handled by OS, so here I would suggest define the interface well and pass the necessary information into the interface through OS calls.

Comment: Why? The OP says there will be just one file per week. I would just make the latest file available as an external table by using the preprocessor (as suggested by @Bjarte) to create a simlink to the latest file and have the external table look at the simlink.